Don't Encode forward slashes in hash-portion of url with AngularJS 1.5.8 and angular-ui-router 0.3.1
I'm embedding a react app within a legacy angularjs with a directive. The angularjs app uses the html5 router for it's routes and React uses HashRouter.
However forward slashes are encoded by angular so they don't hit the routes in react.
So for example:
https://my-app.com/angularroute/#/react/route/5

turns into:
https://my-app.com/angularroute/#%2Freact%2Froute%2F5

How can I setup so that the hash-portion of the URI doesn't get encoded?
(The angularjs codebase I'm working on is fairly large, so updating to a newer angular och router version would be a secondary option. Current versions: AngularJS 1.5.8 and angular-ui-router 0.3.1)
